# HDMI/DP PC to USB-C Thunderbolt 3 Monitor

Tags: usb, hdmi, thunderbolt, video-adapters, cable

This is 2019.

Is there any adapter that can display the video signal of a HDMI/DP device like a tv-box, PC or Notebook to a thunderbolt 3 Display?

The other way around doesn't count.

**Edit:** [Delock has made it!](https://www.delock.com/produkt/85812/merkmale.html) It should be at least compatible with all USB-C Alt mode compatible displays.

They also have good HDMI male to DP female adapters with an extra usb for power on the HDMI side, not at 4k@60hz  like on the first cable, but still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Delock has made one explicitly called [USB-C to bidirectional DP Alt mode Cable!](https://www.delock.com/produkt/85812/merkmale.html)
Everyone, hooray for [Delock!](https://www.delock.com/produkt/85812/merkmale.html)

Comment: This may work for many USB-C displays, but anyone looking at this recommendation should know that the cable does not support DisplayPort to Thunderbolt 3. DisplayPort via Thunderbolt-3 (on a USB-C connector) and DisplayPort Alternate Mode via USB-C are different video signals!

Comment: Thank you for sharing your intel with us, TB3 is backwards compatible with USB-C Alt mode right? What you're saying is funny, because of how Virtuallink is different.

Comment: Thunderbolt 3 *hosts* are backwards compatible with USB-C, that is correct. But Thunderbolt 3 *displays* may be expecting a thunderbolt-format DisplayPort signal. It is possible that some "Thunderbolt 3" displays do not support USB-C Alt-Mode at all, because Thunderbolt 3 itself provides an alternative DisplayPort implementation.

Comment: And [VirtualLink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualLink) is a USB-C alt mode. Not related to TB3 at all. Right now mostly video cards and specific ports on gaming laptops have support for VirtualLink, not all USB-C outputs!

Comment: Good thinking! And thanks for sharing that last one as well, didn't got a clue.

Answer (score 1):

**Revised Answer:**

After taking a closer look at USB-C or Thunderbolt 3 and how they achieve video output, I don't think an adapter exists to connect an HDMI video source to connect to a USB-C display. Even the [official HDMI website](https://www.hdmi.org/spec/typec) shows the conversion as being one-way: USB-C to HDMI.

A major caveat is that sending HDMI over USB-C requires the video source to send additional signals that are not part of the HDMI specification; They're part of the USB-C specification.

For conversion in this direction to work, an adapter would have to be a USB-C Host controller and signal to the monitor that it wants to use the HDMI alternate mode. Creating a video adapter that acts as a USB-C host device is not trivial, and almost pointless since most devices or screens have multiple video connectors to use instead.

I believe that it may be *possible* to make such an adapter, but the demand for it is too low for any to exist yet.

---

**Old Answer:**

*"This is 2019."* Yes, but [new video connectors don't always make things simpler.](https://xkcd.com/927/)

To answer your question seriously, the thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) connection uses a DisplayPort signal for video. Unfortunately HDMI to DisplayPort (in that direction) is not compatible with just a simple wire-to-wire converter. You actually need something known as an "Active HDMI to Displayport Adapter", and obviously the displayport side needs to be the USB-C connector.

I am also fairly certain that the USB-C monitors get their power from the USB-C connection. If you have a monitor like that, the adapter would have to supply power too!

I have never seen an adapter that meets all of those requirements so I cannot recommend one for you.

<s>It might be possible to combine two adapters:</s>

1. HDMI -> DisplayPort
   This one must be active, so requires its own power usually from USB.
2. DisplayPort -> USB-C
   <s>This one may be VERY hard to find in this direction but theoretically possible.</s> (It probably doesn't exist.)

Old Update:

It turns out that I entirely missed that USB-C (and thunderbolt 3) can output HDMI signals too (*as an [Alternate Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#Alternate_Mode_2) on top of USB-C*). <s>That implies that USB-C displays (but not necessarily ones that *require* Thunderbolt 3) can accept HDMI signals through that connector. This raises some hope that there is a passive HDMI to USB-C cable/adapter out there.</s> (This isn't possible without negotiating the video mode over USB first.)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I thought it was also compatible with HDMI since visa versa exists. Also my monitor has the extra power ;), but I am totally familiar with that issue lol. so 2 display port adapters it is!

Comment: Wait your telling me there's no DP to TB3 adapter cause Displayport mode is not backwards compatible with displayports? that's lame. which year is it? I'm actually LMAO-ing right now hah. Like u can only connect a new TB3 device to TB2 displays, we don't wanna sell new ones.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update, I'm happy to here that. now I have to search 1 cable less.

Comment: @KevinCrans, I'm reading elsewhere that a passive HDMI <--> USB-C cable did not work with an HP portable monitor, it will depend on the portable monitor you're using whether the passive cable *could* work, since some USB-C inputs don't accept HDMI. (I presume the ones that call themselves thunderbolt displays?)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll be careful. Fortunately USB 3.1 wouldn't be a problem for me. I would earlier suspect the cable though. Any known source of this cable?

Comment: @KevinCrans, No info sorry. Here's the [question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1437748/hdmi-to-usb-c-monitor) that could actually be considered a duplicate of this. I suspect that HP screen just doesn't support HDMI over USB-C, but it might be hard to find since Thunderbolt and USB-C defined the DisplayPort mode first. Monitor manufacturers will probably opt for that as the "default" mode assuming the output is a USB-C port on the PC too.

Comment: I respect that it is more of a Displayport job, or that Thunderbolt 3 displays need additional power (even though I have a separate cable), but I laugh at that Displayport mode is not compatible with actual Displayports, which never required additional power in the first place.

Comment: Actually the power can go both ways... There are enterprise-class displays which also work as USB hubs all the while charging your notebook. All over a single USB-C cable.

Comment: Why doesn't both ways go to an HDMI/DP connector than? Is the one who disliked responsible for that? Else, where to find it than? I think what you are saying is about usb to usb, so I flag your comment for topic relevance. Laptops with only HDMI and mini DP do not work with that if your have a display with USB C 3.1 or with Thunderbolt 3.

Comment: HDMI does not output power. So something like a laptop or TV box would not send power over an HDMI --> USB-C adapter. As mentioned earlier, this means the USB-C display would need its own power cable. Since this is a very unusual use-case for HDMI and USB-C, there just isn't any demand or reason to make an adapter that goes HDMI to USB-C for only video. People who buy that adapter might try to use it backwards and return the product in frustration because their USB-C or TB3 port wouldn't output HDMI video without a proper USB-C device on the other end.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but again my display is powered by another cable. And there is demand, if you have an old device and want to upgrade your display. Why would you use anything besides C5, C7 or C13/C14 to charge your display (Usb charge is for phones). Than the situation that I have is even more realistic. You can't always upgrade your device, but you can always upgrade the peripherals attached to it, sadly this isn't true, so either the protocol has a bug, or the manufacturers are very disappointing in at least their own Thunderbolt 2 connectivity.

Comment: @KevinCrans, USB-C displays are almost exclusively intended to be used with laptops that have USB-C. Connecting them to other devices is not an expected use-case, and if too few people want to use the product that way, manufacturers won't consider it profitable to support those users by implementing non-standard functionality. (*Like passive HDMI over USB-C*) Also, USB-C can output 100W of power so it is often used for charging laptops and portable displays with batteries.

Comment: Lastly, if you choose to upgrade your peripherals, you have the power to choose something that is *compatible* with your device. USB-C is not a replacement for HDMI, it is an upgrade for USB-A. Video output over USB-C is *backwards compatible* with other displays, but you are asking for a way to make a TV box or HDMI device to be *forwards compatible* with a newer display connector. I'm fairly certain that USB-C displays require a **USB-C Host** as a video source since the HDMI or DP video mode needs to be negotiated over the USB-C protocol.

Comment: I was wrong about the charging, but I didn't call HDMI once in my latest comment. Thunderbolt 3 displays not supporting Thunderbolt 2 is just amateurism, think logical. What's a DP mode without supporting a DP source? sounds like a joke to me. Backwards compatibility to an unique device sounds more important than backwards compatibility for another the same display, just older (for a cable at least).

Comment: @KevinCrans, I don't really understand what you're trying to say, or why you have changed the conversation to talking about Thunderbolt 2, that is not in the scope of your question. Your question was about HDMI or DP into a USB-C display, and if you have any new questions about Thunderbolt 2 you should ask a new question on the appropriate stack exchange site.

Comment: @KevinCrans, Thunderbolt 3, and like basically any other computer I/O connection, is backwards compatible on the *host* side because that is where it make sense to put the more complex and expensive chipsets that support backwards compatibility. You can use a Thunderbolt 2 display on a Thunderbolt 3 computer because Thunderbolt 3 *host controllers* can output older Thunderbolt 2 signals. You cannot convert Thunderbolt 2 signals into Thunderbolt 3 signals. Therefore Thunderbolt 3 displays require.... Thunderbolt 3.

Comment: Alt DP's backwards incompatibility damages it's own display's sales, as licenses for an unpopular display standard on a device's next model may be more expensive than releasing it with new HDMI/DP2, being backwards compatible and more popular. There's no HDMI/DP adapter for Alt DP display, leaves charging it's only use, making C7 maybe cheaper on displays and making HDMI or DP2 maybe cheaper on devices(no adapter). The benefit would of course be providing the functionality trough a single port, for more beautiful phone design, even though the ROG Phone 2 with 3 of them looks just as beautiful.

Comment: @KevinCrans, I believe your replies on this answer have diverged from the topic of the question and are not relevant to my answer either. If you have more questions about DisplayPort, Thunderbolt, USB-C, etc. I would be glad to attempt to answer them on the relevant stack exchange site. I will finish by saying that USB-C monitors exist to serve a very specific purpose. They are not going to *replace* devices that come with DP or HDMI, so your comments about being bad for sales are irrelevant; These displays are *only meant for* USB-C devices, there is no expectation of backwards compatibility.

Comment: I agree, the point is, it's made for embedded devices like phones and macs, not necessary for PC's, GPU's and Game Consoles and useless on displays. My fault for being mistaken asking this question.